# $p$-cycle in $S_p$ lies in certain subgroup.

Tags: group-theory, permutations

I am reading Ruffini's work on equations and permutation groups, say this https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/41133596.pdf. However, Theorem 7 in the article is a statement I can't come up with a solution. It says:

If $G$ is a subgroup of $S_p$, where $p$ is a prime, and $t \in G$, $t \ne e$. Let $\pi$ be a $p$-cycle such that $\pi^it\pi^{-i} \in G$ for all $i$, then $\pi \in G$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $H = \langle \pi^i t \pi^{-i} : 0 \le i < p \rangle$. Then, by hypothesis, $H \le G$, and $\pi \in N_G(H)$. We shall prove that $\pi \in H$.

Assume not. Then $|\langle H, \pi \rangle| = p|H|$, so  $p$ cannot divide $|H|$. Hence $H$ cannot be a transitive subgroup of $S_p$. Since $\pi \in N_G(H)$, $\pi$ must permute the orbits of $H$, and since $\langle \pi \rangle$ is transitive, it must permute the orbits transitively. So the orbits of $H$ all have the same size, which is impossible because $p$ is prime.